# Restore deleted home directory

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, data-recovery, restore, testdisk

There are a lof of answers in regards to this issue, but unfortunately I did not grasp how to make them work

I accidentaly deleted almost all home directory (the directory itself is remaining, but now contains negligible amount of files). I interested in restoring my information, in parcticular in txt, py, ipynb files.

1. After deleteting I booted from the LiveUSB and didn't mount the Ubuntu parition (I did mount the partition containing the second OS - W7)
2. testdisks - advanced utils: restored some files, but not the ones I need
3. extundelete also didn't restored the needed files
4. scalpel failed with a mistake after a one hour of searching (unfortunately, I have not written down the error message: it was something like 'node did not found', and the laptop didn't react at all)
5. Photorec - returned a huge amount of data with broken names, I did not figure out how to handle it. I tried to narrow the search by opting out the type of files, but I found in the list of options only 'pyc' files but no 'py' files. Do you know how can I add it?

As far as I understand I could try GREP option with mentioning the initial string of the files (in my case it would be either '!#usr', ''', """ or 'import'). Could you please give me any advice about that option.

I also have read that I can restore the partition table via testdisk >> analyse. But I don't know, is it fit for my case (as my partition table is apparently OK)?

Is there anything else I can do?

Isn't it strange, that none of the attempts successeded? Maybe I messed up something, as after only two minutes I rebooted the laptop from a liveUSB. I am quite new to Linux and I am very surprised that there is no way to restore the infomation. Hope, that I did something wrong:) and there is a way to redeem.

I deleted files via python script(I wanted to delete 'temp' directory but instead deleted it's parent)

Lubuntu 16.04, Acer Aspire 5750ZG

Comment: Sounds like your partition table is fine. How did you delete the files in your home directory?

Comment: @WJAndrea, I deleted files via python script(I wanted to delete 'temp' directory but instead deleted it's parent)